Query plan seems to depend on time interval between query and table setup?
I am working with PostgreSQL 17. As an example, I have a table table0 with a column col0, with randomly generated strings as GIN-indexed values. I use the following setup.sql to create such a table:
create table public.table0 (
    col0 varchar(25)
);

select setseed(0.12345);

insert into table0 (col0)
select substring(md5(random()::text), 1, (2 + (random() * 14))::int)
from generate_series(1, 12345678);

create extension pg_trgm;
create index col0_gin_trgm_idx on table0 using gin (col0 gin_trgm_ops);

vacuum (full, analyze) table0;

Using select setseed(0.12345); ensures the created table is the same at every execution of setup.sql. I would like to observe the execution plan for a simple partial string match query. To do so, I use query.sql:
explain (analyze, buffers)
select * from table0 where col0 like '%abc%' limit 500;

To my surprise, the execution plan of the query is not constant, and it seemingly depends on the time between table creation and query execution. To demonstrate this, I create the following bash script:
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

rm -f records.txt

for i in {1..9}; do

    docker run \
        --name postgres-db \
        --env POSTGRES_DB=postgres \
        --env POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
        --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
        --publish 5432:5432\
        --detach postgres

    sleep 2 # wait for docker container to start

    PGPASSWORD=mysecretpassword psql \
        --host=localhost \
        --port=5432 \
        --username=postgres \
        --dbname=postgres \
        --set=ON_ERROR_STOP=1 \
        --file=setup.sql

    sleep $((RANDOM % 10))

    PGPASSWORD=mysecretpassword psql \
        --host=localhost \
        --port=5432 \
        --username=postgres \
        --dbname=postgres \
        --set=ON_ERROR_STOP=1 \
        --file=query.sql >> records.txt

    docker rm --force postgres-db

done

This scripts sets up the table, waits a random amount up to 10 seconds, and then executes the above query.sql. It does several times. It saves query.sql outputs to records.txt. I looked at records.txt and found that sometimes sequential scan, sometimes index scan is used to perform the query. A filtered (via cat records.txt | grep "\->") version of records.txt:
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.34..4394.93 rows=1219 width=10) (actual time=11.526..15.200 rows=500 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.04 rows=1219 width=0) (actual time=9.559..9.559 rows=20852 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on table0  (cost=0.00..216612.01 rows=122742 width=9) (actual time=0.068..17.788 rows=500 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.34..4394.93 rows=1219 width=9) (actual time=5.963..8.939 rows=500 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.04 rows=1219 width=0) (actual time=4.144..4.144 rows=20852 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.32..4377.97 rows=1214 width=9) (actual time=7.447..11.406 rows=500 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.01 rows=1214 width=0) (actual time=5.594..5.594 rows=20852 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.33..4384.75 rows=1216 width=9) (actual time=6.660..11.991 rows=500 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.02 rows=1216 width=0) (actual time=4.744..4.745 rows=20852 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.34..4394.93 rows=1219 width=9) (actual time=9.153..13.563 rows=500 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.04 rows=1219 width=0) (actual time=7.141..7.141 rows=20852 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.31..4374.58 rows=1213 width=10) (actual time=10.078..13.199 rows=500 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.01 rows=1213 width=0) (actual time=8.108..8.108 rows=20852 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.33..4384.76 rows=1216 width=10) (actual time=7.322..12.073 rows=500 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.02 rows=1216 width=0) (actual time=5.526..5.527 rows=20852 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on table0  (cost=0.00..216610.51 rows=245232 width=9) (actual time=0.073..23.047 rows=500 loops=1)

The complete records.txt is:
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52.34..1833.55 rows=500 width=10) (actual time=11.527..15.249 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.34..4394.93 rows=1219 width=10) (actual time=11.526..15.200 rows=500 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=428
         Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.04 rows=1219 width=0) (actual time=9.559..9.559 rows=20852 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
               Buffers: shared hit=4 read=7
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=51 read=13 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 4.666 ms
 Execution Time: 15.657 ms
(13 rows)

                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..882.39 rows=500 width=9) (actual time=0.068..17.831 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared read=1439
   ->  Seq Scan on table0  (cost=0.00..216612.01 rows=122742 width=9) (actual time=0.068..17.788 rows=500 loops=1)
         Filter: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 282649
         Buffers: shared read=1439
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=55 read=9 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 2.427 ms
 Execution Time: 17.918 ms
(10 rows)

                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52.34..1833.55 rows=500 width=9) (actual time=5.965..8.988 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.34..4394.93 rows=1219 width=9) (actual time=5.963..8.939 rows=500 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=428
         Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.04 rows=1219 width=0) (actual time=4.144..4.144 rows=20852 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
               Buffers: shared hit=4 read=7
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=51 read=13 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 2.427 ms
 Execution Time: 9.234 ms
(13 rows)

                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52.32..1833.89 rows=500 width=9) (actual time=7.448..11.454 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.32..4377.97 rows=1214 width=9) (actual time=7.447..11.406 rows=500 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=428
         Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.01 rows=1214 width=0) (actual time=5.594..5.594 rows=20852 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
               Buffers: shared hit=4 read=7
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=81 read=13 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 2.835 ms
 Execution Time: 11.721 ms
(13 rows)

                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52.33..1833.75 rows=500 width=9) (actual time=6.662..12.059 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.33..4384.75 rows=1216 width=9) (actual time=6.660..11.991 rows=500 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=428
         Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.02 rows=1216 width=0) (actual time=4.744..4.745 rows=20852 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
               Buffers: shared hit=4 read=7
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=51 read=13 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 3.332 ms
 Execution Time: 12.511 ms
(13 rows)

                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52.34..1833.55 rows=500 width=9) (actual time=9.154..13.621 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.34..4394.93 rows=1219 width=9) (actual time=9.153..13.563 rows=500 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=428
         Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.04 rows=1219 width=0) (actual time=7.141..7.141 rows=20852 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
               Buffers: shared hit=4 read=7
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=51 read=13 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 4.113 ms
 Execution Time: 14.018 ms
(13 rows)

                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52.31..1833.95 rows=500 width=10) (actual time=10.079..13.249 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.31..4374.58 rows=1213 width=10) (actual time=10.078..13.199 rows=500 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=428
         Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.01 rows=1213 width=0) (actual time=8.108..8.108 rows=20852 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
               Buffers: shared hit=4 read=7
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=51 read=13 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 3.596 ms
 Execution Time: 13.682 ms
(13 rows)

                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52.33..1833.75 rows=500 width=10) (actual time=7.323..12.126 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.33..4384.76 rows=1216 width=10) (actual time=7.322..12.073 rows=500 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=428
         Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.02 rows=1216 width=0) (actual time=5.526..5.527 rows=20852 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
               Buffers: shared hit=4 read=7
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=51 read=13 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 5.907 ms
 Execution Time: 12.485 ms
(13 rows)

                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..441.64 rows=500 width=9) (actual time=0.074..23.096 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared read=1439
   ->  Seq Scan on table0  (cost=0.00..216610.51 rows=245232 width=9) (actual time=0.073..23.047 rows=500 loops=1)
         Filter: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 282649
         Buffers: shared read=1439
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=51 read=13 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 2.087 ms
 Execution Time: 23.218 ms
(10 rows)

I used dockerised Postgres 17 to provide easy reproducibility.
Restarting the docker container, running setup.sql, and then:
explain (analyze, buffers, settings)
select * from table0 where col0 like '%abc%' limit 500;

returns:
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=52.32..1833.89 rows=500 width=9) (actual time=9.476..17.923 rows=500 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table0  (cost=52.32..4377.97 rows=1214 width=9) (actual time=9.475..17.858 rows=500 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
         Heap Blocks: exact=428
         Buffers: shared hit=4 read=435
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on col0_gin_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..52.01 rows=1214 width=0) (actual time=7.662..7.662 rows=20852 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((col0)::text ~~ '%abc%'::text)
               Buffers: shared hit=4 read=7
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=55 read=9 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 5.597 ms
 Execution Time: 18.334 ms
(13 rows)

Yet, I am not able to understand why sometimes a sequential scan, sometimes an index scan is used.
Why does a query plan seemingly depend on the time interval between the query and table setup?

Below I address some questions which came up in the comments.
Is there any other write activity in the DB?
I did not initiate any, and since it's just a container I run on my local machine, unless there is some automated process I am not aware of, there isn't any writing activity.
How busy is your server otherwise?
I haven't noticed anything not working fine. It's an Apple M1 Pro, running MacOS Sonoma 14.5.

like '%abc%'forces the database to scan the complete table

@nbk That's obviously not true. The trigram index is good for it.

@ErwinBrandstetter see the plan it isn't that good and it is slow

Could you elaborate more on what you mean by "scan the complete table", @nbk? The query plans clearly contradict the naive interpretation, ie that like forces a sequential scan. 7 out of 10 times col0_gin_trgm_idx was used, and not a sequential scan.

@nbk Why do you think it’s slow? I don’t see any timing at all in the query plans, no analyze has been used. These are just plans, without any information about performance or speed

@FrankHeikens, would rewriting the question with explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) be helpful in this particular case? (I'm slightly worried about making the question less clear by making it longer, but if you think it would help then I'm convinced.)

@zabop: Yes, explain (analyze, buffers) is always more helpful. And explain (analyze, buffers, settings) once to show non-default settings - odd server config may play a role. (I don't care about verbose.) [edit] the question with results. There may be additional effects, explain analyze actually executes the query, thereby pulling relevant data pages into cache mem. Also, is there any other write activity in the DB? And how busy is your server otherwise?

@ErwinBrandstetter, I edited the question, I hope I have addressed your points. To me, the content of explain (analyze, buffers) is identical to that of  explain (analyze, buffers, settings) - the reason behind this is unclear to me, perhaps that's another topic I should look into.

@zabop: The reason is simple. You are running with all default settings. Which means, among others random_page_cost = 4, which is way too conservative with modern hardware (SSD) and databases that can mostly be cached (RAM >> DB size). After SET random_page_cost = 1.1;, the problem will go away immediately. But that leaves some aspects of your question unanswered. (Some relevant settings for your case: SELECT name, setting FROM   pg_settings WHERE name = ANY ( '{shared_buffers , effective_cache_size , random_page_cost , effective_io_concurrency , work_mem }'::text[]);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows that actual times are not far apart between seq scan vs. bitmap idx scan. random_page_cost = 4 made it a close call for the planner estimates. The actual perf. difference will be more pronounced the bigger the table gets (pro index).

The high numbers for read buffers does not go down, even after many invocations. I would expect to see mostly or all hits eventually, after data pages have been cached. Obviously, I don't understand your dockerized setup, or there is a problem with (too little) cache mem ...

You’re testing in Docker, on a small dataset, using a default configuration on a rather fast system. No matter how a query will be executed, it will always be fast. There is hardly any difference between your fast and slow queries

I only realized after looking more closely at your setup: You recreate the whole DB for every iteration in your loop.
You use setseed() to recreate the exact same table contents. That's good for recreating a stable testbed. But setseed() only applies to random() and random_normal() calls in the same session, not to ANALYZE, which collects statistics based on its own random selection of rows. Hence random variations within a standard distribution are to be expected for column statistics between iterations. That's reflected in slight variations in the row estimates in the query plans.
I recreated your scenario and got 20852 of the total 12345678 rows containing 'abc'. To satisfy your LIMIT 500, Postgres needs to read (12345678 / 20852) * 500 = 296031 rows on avg., which isn't that much more expensive than running a bitmap index scan over the trigram GIN index. Bad planner constants can lead the query planner astray if the stats overestimate the frequency of your search pattern just enough.
Solution
You obviously have fast hardware. The default setting of random_page_cost = 4 is misleading for cost estimation. I expect a more realistic setting of random_page_cost = 1.1 (as suggested in the manual) to put an end to any sequential scan in the given scenario, as that roughly quadruples the relative cost estimation.
You might also test with a substantially smaller LIMIT, or a longer (more selective) search pattern, or optimize some other config settings that make index usage (realistically!) cheaper in the planner estimates, or increase the statistics target for the table (or just the one column) as suggested in the manual:

For large tables, ANALYZE takes a random sample of the table
contents, rather than examining every row. This allows even very large
tables to be analyzed in a small amount of time. Note, however, that
the statistics are only approximate, and will change slightly each
time ANALYZE is run, even if the actual table contents did not
change. This might result in small changes in the planner's estimated
costs shown by EXPLAIN. In rare situations, this non-determinism
will cause the planner's choices of query plans to change after
ANALYZE is run. To avoid this, raise the amount of statistics
collected by ANALYZE, as described below.

The "described below" part leads to:
ALTER TABLE table0 ALTER COLUMN col0 SET STATISTICS 1000;

See:

How to check statistics targets used by ANALYZE?

All to the same effect that seq scans for the case should go away.
Aside 1: VACUUM (FULL, ANALYZE) is overkill, VACUUM (ANALYZE) would be good enough (and much cheaper) for your pristine DB.
Aside 2: Better yet (and much cheaper, yet), create a "template" database once in your DB cluster, and recreate identical databases (with identical column statistics!) with:
CREATE DATABASE template_db_copy TEMPLATE template_db;

See:

How to copy a Postgres database within the same DB cluster?


Raising "the amount of statistics collected by ANALYZE" did help to trigger the usage of the index. I haven't yet been able to observe that changing random_page_cost alters the situation, but I'm working on it.
